# String no findViewById

Tags: java, android, imageview, id

Olá, queria saber se tem como usar um string no findViewById.
Tenho um app com varios imageview que quando precisando chama uma intent para a camera do celular. Para que eu não precise colocar essa intent e o seu startActivityforResult para cada imageview, pensei em criar uma string para mudar o Id de cada imageview de acordo com a imageview selecionada.
Ex:

```
 image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id(aqui colocar o código de uma string);
 image.setImageBitmap(imageCamera);
```

É possível?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro você fazer isso usando um `HashMap`, já que quer ter controle via `String`.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put("Image1",R.id.imageView1);
    map.put("Image2",R.id.imageView2);
    map.put("Image3",R.id.imageView3);
```

Para recuperar o id, para o seu `findView`, você faria algo assim:

```
 image=(ImageView)findViewById(map.get("Image1"));
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: Legal! Que bom que ajudei. Abs